# Share webpages on social media with counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm creating a website that's going to have hundreds of pages. I want each page to be shareable on **Facebook** and **Twitter**. I've already created these buttons but I also want to have their respective share counters next to my share buttons. I don't want to use the standard Facebook method they provide because the coding looks bloated.

Right, so after doing some research, I found [this example on codepen](http://codepen.io/graygilmore/pen/oclvb).

This looks exactly what I want - very simple!

However, I need some clarification and basic help with how this javascript code works:

```
var permalink = 'http://codepen.io';

var getTwitterCount = function () {
$.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json? 
url='+permalink+'&callback=?', function(data){
var twitterShares = data.count;
$('.twitter .share-count').text(twitterShares);
});
};

getTwitterCount();


var getFacebookCount = function () {
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids='+permalink+'&callback=?',     
function(data){
var facebookShares = data[permalink].shares;
$('.facebook .share-count').text(facebookShares);
});
};

getFacebookCount();
```

This bit of code:

```
var permalink = 'http://codepen.io';
```

Does this have to be:

**1)** the url of the actual page I want shared, eg: http://www.example.com/page-1/

OR

**2)** Must this be the root of the domain name, eg: http://www.example.com/

?

Or am I missing something else?

If the answer is #1 above, then that means I have to include + edit this line for each page which isn't ideal because I have all my javascript code + plugins in ONE .js file to reduce http requests, so I'd prefer it that I don't have to add this javascript on-page for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the page that you want to share, but you could get around it without using a separate variable for each page by setting it to something like `document.location.href` for example?

Comment: I see your solution and I can see the logic behind it, however I wouldn't know how to implement that into the code unfortunately (I'm not good with javascript at all)

Comment: document.location.href is the URL for the current page.  You'd just replace the string 'http://codepen.io' with document.location.href, so your first line would read: var permalink = document.location.href;

Comment: Are you 100% sure this will work?? Obviously my pages have never been shared before because they still need to be developed, so after testing your solution, the .share-count elements are of course blank (no numbers) ... should they be showing a zero "0" ? I just don't want to be creating my pages thinking solutions works when it may not ... and I can't do any tests (by sharing) because the website is still under construction.

Comment: You can test this if you want to be certain.  Run once with that string set to a URL that you know has been shared (e.g. http://codepen.io as you have been using), and also use an alert, or a console.log to ensure that document.location.href returns the URL of your current page as you'd expect.  If you want to be doubly certain, you could do the same in a number of different browsers, but yes, that is definitely the case as you can see from this W3Schools example (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp)

Comment: Damn, I would probably have to return to the SO community just to be able to setup that test you're suggesting (yup I'm that useless). I can't get why your solution + the Pen isn't a big hit thus being easy to find online! Okay so should I trust that your solution will work?

Comment: OKAY! I tested your solution on the actual pen that I linked in my question and it WORKS (luckily that page / pen had been shared before)!

Comment: Sorry, missed your previous comment.  As a rule, I'd say NEVER trust code you've got from someone else without testing it yourself - helps you to understand what it's doing as well as verifying that it does what you expect.  As you've found, testing it not too bad in this case though.  Glad all sorted now.